# NuxtJS - npm run build command not working

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

When i type the command "npm run build" that call the command "nuxt start -c ./phiv/nuxt.config.js" on my NuxtJs project i received this error message that i dont understand :

[image: Error message]

Is there someone that could help me to understand the meaning of this error message and what i have to search for ? I searched for a long time and i dont have a clue of what going wrong...

I thank you in advance for your help

there is the nuxt.config.js that is called by the npm run build command also :

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const defaultConf = require('../nuxt.config.js');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') dotenv.config({ path: 'phiv/.env' });

module.exports = {
  ...defaultConf,
  head: {
    ...defaultConf.head,
    meta: defaultConf.head.meta.concat([
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ]),
    link: defaultConf.head.link.concat([
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/x-icon',
        href: '/favicon.png',
      },
    ]),
    script: defaultConf.head.script.concat([
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: `${process.env.ENV === 'production' ? '//tag.aticdn.net/597349/smarttag.js' : '//tag.aticdn.net/602021/smarttag.js'}`,
      },
    ]),
  },
  dir: {
    layouts: '../layouts',
    static: '../static',
    store: '../store',
    assets: '../assets',
  },
  srcDir: 'phiv/',
  env: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_HOST,
    API_PATIENT_URL: process.env.API_PATIENT_URL,
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
    B2B_URI: process.env.B2B_URI,
    ENV: process.env.ENV,
    MAP_TILE: process.env.MAP_TILE,
    ALGOLIA_APP_ID: process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
    ALGOLIA_API_KEY: process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY,
    SENTRY_URL: process.env.SENTRY_URL,
    SITE: 'mypharmactiv',
  },
  build: {
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      config.resolve.alias.Project = `${config.resolve.alias['~~']}/components/phiv/`;

      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        });
      }

      // SVG Loader
      const svgRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => {
        if (!rule.use || !Array.isArray(rule.use)) return false;
        if (rule.use[0].loader === 'url-loader') return true;
        return false;
      });
      svgRule.test = /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/;
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'vue-svg-loader',
      });
    },
    // extractCSS: true,
    postcss: {
      preset: {
        autoprefixer: {
          grid: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you try use @ insted of ../ 
 something like this dir: { layouts: '@/layouts'

Comment: and your nuxt.config is too really strange!